# split a table cell in two lines and columns

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

what is the best way to split a table cell like this:

```
| Header1    | Header2| Header3  |
----------------------------------
| text11      | text12 | text13   |
----------------------------------
| text21      | text22 | text23   |
----------------------------------
|       |t311 |text312 | text313  | 
| text31|     |        |          |  
|       |t312 |text322 | text323 |
```

thanks

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: Check out this page for easy table creation in Latex. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ Create your table using GUI on the site and automatically generate Latex code for the table you created. This site saved a lot of my time! And headache to create table in latex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | c | c |}
  \hline 
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Header1}    & Header2 & Header3  \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{text11}      & text12 & text13   \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{text21}     & text22 & text23   \\
  \hline
  \multirow{2}*{text31}      & t311 &text312 & text313  \\
       & t312 & text322 & text323 \\
  \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that tabular with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{llcc}[hvlines]
  \Block{1-2}{Header1} &      & Header2 & Header3 \\
  \Block{1-2}{text11}  &      & text12  & text13  \\
  \Block{1-2}{text21}  &      & text22  & text23  \\
  \Block{2-1}{text31}  & t311 & text312 & text313 \\
                       & t312 & text322 & text323 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]