# Actual split cell in tabular

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

Look at these questions and their answers:

[Splitting a row to two rows in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149232/splitting-a-row-to-two-rows-in-latex)

[split a table cell in two lines and columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345211/split-a-table-cell-in-two-lines-and-columns/345219)

They present similar issues and, similar accepted answers. However, the answer is not exactly the solution to the questions.

I found them because I raised the same question: **how to ACTUALLY split cells?**

Observe that this is not a duplicate, since I focus on the splitting action instead of merging most of cells. In fact, as a matter of illustration, the merging action is a solution for those working with Excell like softwares, while the splitting action is common for those working with tables in Word like softwares.

Comment: What do you mean by "actually split"? Automatic line breaking? Change to a small table?

Comment: Like split a cell into two either vertically or horizontally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use nested tabular in order to split cells horizontally and/or vertically:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Split cells horizontally:

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
some text & some more text \\ 
\hline
non split cell & \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
                   split cell A & split cell B \\
                 \end{tabular}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Split cells vertically:

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
some text & some more text \\ 
\hline
non split cell & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
                   split cell A\\
                   split cell B\\
                 \end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Split cells horizontally and vertically:

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
some text & some more text \\ 
\hline
non split cell & \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
                   split cell A & split cell B\\
                   split cell C & split cell D\\
                 \end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Brasil: You're welcome. However, you might want to keep in mind that the above posted solution has some limitation especially when it comes to horizontal lines in the nested tabulars.