# Split cells vertical and horizontal

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, multicolumn, cline

[image]

I'm an absolute newby in Latex and I try to reproduce a table (see picture above) as an exercise in university. I need to split cells both vertically and horizontally, as can be seen in the picture. Further, I need to give the table a caption. With my code, I can split lines horizontally but for a vertical split, I can't find a solution that is working for me.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}
  \hline 
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{learning process}  & learning tools & search space  \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{feature engineering}  & (subsequent) classifiers & feature sets   \\
  \cline{3-3} 
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}  &    & feature enhancing methods and their hyper-parameters   \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{model selection}  & classifiers & classifiers and their hyper-parameters   \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{optimization algorithm selection}  & classifiers & algorithms and their hyper-parameters   \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:table-name}Caption}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** This is the information I have regarding the type of my document:

```
%\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,BCOR=12mm,DIV=12]{scrbook} % two-sided % original source stated: BCOR=12mm,DIV=12 \documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,DIV=12]{scrbook} % one-sided
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Cells can not be split, they can be only merged :-).  With ``multicolumn` and `multirow`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @Zarko: Regarding: "Cells can not be split, they can be only merged": Actually, you *can* sort of split table cells using nested tabulars as explained for example here: [Actual split cell in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490193/134144)

Comment: @leandriis, nesting tables in cells doesn't split this cell ... but insert new table in it. Well, this you can consider, that this cell is split :-)

Comment: @Zarko: That's why I wrote "sort of". However, I totally agree that using `multicolumn` and `multirow` is way better in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the following solution provide what you like to obtain:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand\mcl[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \sffamily
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
      \centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{l|}}
  \hline
\mcl{\textbf{learning process}}      
    &   \textbf{learning tools}            
        &   \textbf{search space}       \\
  \hline
\mcl{\multirow{2}{*}{feature engineering}}  
        & \multirow{2}{*}{(subsequent) classifiers}
            & feature sets              \\
  \cline{4-4}
\mcl{}  
        &   & feature enhancing methods and their hyper-parameters   \\
  \hline
\mcl{model selection}  
        & classifiers
            & classifiers and their hyper-parameters   \\
  \hline
\mcl{optimization algorithm selection}  
        & classifiers
            & algorithms and their hyper-parameters   \\
  \hline
\multirow{2}{12mm}{full scope}
    &   general
        & classifiers
            &   xxx \\
  \cline{2-4}
    &   neural arcitecture search (NAS)
        &   neural networks
            &   networtk structure              \\     
  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
\label{tab:table-name}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Table using `tabularx` table environment which enable multi lines text in cells:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcl[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \sffamily
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l
                             |l
                             |>{\hsize=0.6\hsize}L
                             |>{\hsize=1.4\hsize}L|}
  \hline
\mcl{\textbf{learning process}}      
    &   \textbf{learning tools}            
        &   \textbf{search space}       \\
  \hline
\mcl{\multirow{3}{*}{feature engineering}}  
        & \multirow{3}{=}{(subsequent) classifiers}
            & feature sets              \\
  \cline{4-4}
\mcl{}  
        &   & feature enhancing methods and their hyper-parameters   \\
  \hline
\mcl{model selection}  
        & classifiers
            & classifiers and their hyper-parameters   \\
  \hline
\mcl{optimization algorithm selection}  
        & classifiers
            & algorithms and their hyper-parameters   \\
  \hline
\multirow{2}{8mm}{full scope}
    &   general
        & classifiers
            &   xxx \\
  \cline{2-4}
    &   neural arcitecture search (NAS)
        &   neural networks
            &   networtk structure              \\     
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Caption}
\label{tab:table-name}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works! Unfortunately it is displayed vertically because it is too wide. Any chance to insert some line breaks so that it can fit horizontally into a pdf document?

Comment: @constiii, we haven't any clue about your page layout. Please extend your code snippet to complete small document, which we can test and see how much space is available for your table. For multi line cells you can use `p` column type or you can employ `tabularx` table environment.

Comment: Thats the information I have:  %\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,BCOR=12mm,DIV=12]{scrbook} % two-sided % original source stated: BCOR=12mm,DIV=12
\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,DIV=12]{scrbook} % one-sided

Comment: @constiii, please add this information to the question that all member of the site will see this.

Comment: I provided everything I think that has a valueable character in my initial post, thanks for reminding me

Comment: @constiii, does table example in addendum to my answer fulfill your expectation?

Comment: Unfortunately, it only shows the left part of the table generated with your code in the document, which means it is too wide. Is there a way that the table automatically adapats to the width of the document?

Comment: @constiii, this is not possible. Table width(in the second example) is equal to text width. It start at left text border and end at right border!

Comment: okay thank you! As an alternative, is it possible to assign a fixed width for each column, so that in combination with tabularx (automatic line breaks) the width-sum of all columns is smaller than the document size?

Comment: @constiii, yes, it is possible. for start, try use `p{<column width>}`. Also with `>{\hsize=x\hsize}Y` where x is multiplier of `X` column width. For more details read `tabularx` documentation. Since the content of your table is unknown, I can't give you an example of it design.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the solution in [@Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509517/5001), except that it (a) uses a `sidewaystable` environment rather than a `table` environment, as the table is quite wide and fits better in the page if it's typeset in landscape format (for portrait format, a small and hard-to-read font size such as `\footnotesize` is required), and (b) uses a non-zero value of the length parameter `\extrarowheight` for a more open "look" of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' environment
\usepackage{array}    % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\usepackage{multirow} % for '\multirow' macro

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault % optional: switch to sans-serif (globally)

\begin{sidewaystable} % 'table' in landscape mode
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open 'look'

\centering

\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{l|}}
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\bfseries learning process}  
   & \bfseries learning tools & \bfseries search space  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{feature engineering}}  
   & \multirow{2}{*}{(subsequent) classifiers} & feature sets \\
  \cline{4-4} 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}  
   & & feature enhancing methods and their hyper-parameters \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{model selection}  
   & classifiers & classifiers and their hyper-parameters   \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{optimization algorithm selection}  
   & classifiers & algorithms and their hyper-parameters\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{full scope} & general 
   & classifiers & a union of search space in feature, model, and/or algorithm \\
\cline{2-4}
   & neural architecture search (NAS) & neural networks & network structures \\
\hline  
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}\label{tab:table-name}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works! Unfortunately it is displayed vertically because it is too wide. Any chance to insert some line breaks so that it can fit horizontally into a pdf document?

Comment: @constiii - Almost everything is *possible*. To create a *useful* solution, though, it would really, really help if you provided some pertinent information about your document, such as the document class, the width of the text block, the main font size, and whether line breaks should be allowed in all columns or in just a few (and, if it's the latter, which ones). These are parameters which I am unable, and unwilling, to guess.